# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence for incorporating word2vec model in my pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, word2vec

I am getting "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." error when I am trying to run my random forest classifier on a heterogenous data--the text data is been fed to word2vec model and I extracted one dimensional numpy array by taking mean of the word2vec vectors for each word in the text row.

Here is the sample of the data am working with:

```
col-A    col-B .....  col-z

100      230   ...... [0.016612869501113892, -0.04279713928699493, .....]
```

where col-z is the numpy array with fixed size of 300 in each row.

Following is the code for calculating mean the word2vec vectors and creating numpy arrays:

```
`    final_data = []
     for i, row in df.iterrows():
         text_vectorized = []
         text = row['col-z']
         for word in text:
             try:
                 text_vectorized.append(list(w2v_model[word]))
             except Exception as e:
                 pass
         try:
             text_vectorized = np.asarray(text_vectorized, dtype='object')
             text_vectorized_mean = list(np.mean(text_vectorized, axis=0))
         except Exception as e:
             text_vectorized_mean = list(np.zeros(100))
             pass
         try:
             len(text_vectorized_mean)
         except:
             text_vectorized_mean = list(np.zeros(100))
         temp_row = np.asarray(text_vectorized_mean, dtype='object')
         final_data.append(temp_row)
    text_array = np.asarray(final_data, dtype='object')`
```

After this, I convert text_array to pandas dataframe and concatenate it with my original dataframe with other numeric columns. But as soon as I try to feed this data into a classifier, it gives me the above error at this line:

```
-->  array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an array from a mixed list containing both numeric values and an another list. Try to flatten the array first using `.ravel()`

For example,

```
text_array = np.asarray(final_data.ravel(), dtype='object')
```

Comment: text_array does not consist of any numeric data, it is just an array of the word vectors from the word2vec model. Also, since final_data is a list, I cannot use ravel on it, though I tried to use it with my text_array directly but still same issue.
Do I need to flatten the array somehow? Can't I use it as is it being 1 dimensional?